# Create local dev environment from cloned symfony 2 project

Tags: git, .htaccess, symfony

I'm trying to clone a repository from github to my local development environment in Symfony2.  **I get a blank page** going to localhost/project/web/app_dev.php, I have done the following.

cloned This tutorial https://github.com/dsyph3r/symblog

- added a .htaccess file
- installed composer and got latest updates

I realise that git ignore means that the developer who pushed the project up has not included some of the files.  I'm not sure what is missing.

Is there a simple step by step process after cloning to complete the development environment?  thanks

Comment: The development of it has stopped in 2013 and it is based on 2.0 (while 2.4 is deprecated as of today)

Comment: True I tried a new project and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a newer version project in symfony 2 here https://github.com/clubmaster.

1/ I cloned the project, in my root folder.

2/ cd to the project folder, installed composer 
   $ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

3/ got lastest updates with 
         $ php composer.phar install

4/ then sorted the permissions as suggested by FyodorX

It now works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something related to permissions. Try setting them like this:

```
$ HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

I recommend reading the official documentation about [installation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html).